# Http Client Abstraction Layer

Tags: java, akka, actor, apache-httpclient-4.x, abstraction

I'm currently in the process of writing an Http Client abstraction layer for my application so I can easily switch between Http Clients in the life cycle of my application. The issue is, all Http Clients currently out there (Apache, Ning, Spray, Ok etc..) all use very different implementations which makes my job very hard.

Now my question is, are there already pre-built projects out there that I can utilize so the only thing I need to do is write the implementations?
If not, what would be the best way to go about it? It might be worth mentioning that my project is entirely Actor based [Akka](http://akka.io/) so interfacing isn't an option.

I'm not asking for written code, just a concept since I can't quite wrap my head about how I would go about doing such thing.

Comment: What's your reasoning for switching HTTP clients? I ask because it sounds more like what you want is an abstraction over your *domain* that can be implemented by different HTTP adapters

Comment: Yes, that's a better terminology for it. I want to be able to switch HTTP adapters easily without much hassle. The reasoning behind this btw, is because a lot of cool and interesting HTTP Clients are yet to be released but we are already working on the domain logic (application) in advance.

Comment: Write your abstraction layer according to what your DOMAIN wants, not the implementation.  Switching HTTP adapters then comes as easy as swapping out any class

Comment: Could you be more specific, what do you mean exactly? I'm not well known with the terms regarding Domain Logic etc. Maybe, create an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Create your own representations of http request and response messages (modeled as case classes).  Then fire these to a pool of http request executor actors that contain the bridging from your abstraction to a concrete impl of your choice.  That way you can swap out the impl in the http request executor w/o having to change any of your other actors that have the need to make http requests.

Comment: @cmbaxter I understand what you are trying to say but doesn't this require a different actor for each type of HttpClient? If you could submit this into an answer that's more elaborate, I can give a better judgement.

Comment: In short yes, but if that's not desirable then you could define a trait for making the http call and then provide multiple impls of the trait for each http library you want to support and then just have one actor that uses an instance of the trait to perform the work.

Comment: @cmbaxter could you create an answer that contains some examples for future people encountering some sort of abstraction problem? I'll mark it as resolved.

Comment: I will try and get something together and post an answer by tomorrow.

Comment: @cmbaxter while I already fixed the issue, would you mind still adding your suggestion as an answer for future people? It's no problem if you don't, but if you do, I will accept it as an answer and you'll gain yourself some rep.

Comment: @MartijnRiemers, done.  Let me know if you need me to expand it more in order to be accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach would be as follows:

Create your own representations of http request and response messages (modeled as case classes). Then fire these to a pool of http request executor actors that contain the bridging from your abstraction to a concrete impl of your choice. That way you can swap out the impl in the http request executor w/o having to change any of your other actors that have the need to make http requests